# Why does skimage regionprops return 4 values for the area

Tags: python, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I want to measure the area of an binary segmented image with skimage.measure.

When i'm printing the result returns 4 values instead of just the amount of pixels.
This is the code:

```
label_image = measure.label(image > threshold, connectivity=image.ndim)
props = measure.regionprops_table(label_image, image, properties=['label','area', 'equivalent_diameter','mean_intensity', 'solidity'])

df = pd.DataFrame(props)
print('Area measured with skimage measure package: ', df.area)
```

And this is the output:

```
Area measured with skimage measure package:  0       2
1    2789
```

I'm only interested in the amount of pixels (4th Value). There's only one segmented element in the image.

How can i only get the 4th and what do the other parameters about?

This is the segmented image:
[image: segmented wound]

Comment: how does you image look like?

Comment: added it to the post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 values because you have 2 objects on the image (really small one and the big one) and `regionprops` returns both object properties. You are printing a `pandas.Series` object where the 1st value is the index and the 2nd is the actual value.

If you print the dataframe `df` you should see 2 rows.

You can print it properly like:

```
for i, v in enumerate(df.area):
    print(f"Object {i} area: {v}")
```